# Converter application error on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hello guys I am making an Android app that convert from binary to decimal and I have made a class called `Binary` and a class called `Decimal` and a function in the `Binary` class that convert from decimal to binary

```
public Binary DtoB(Decimal decimal)
{
    String temp = null;
    do
    {
        if(decimal.decimal%2!=0)
            temp+='1';
        else
            temp+='0';
        decimal.decimal/=2;
    }while(decimal.decimal>0);
    while(temp.length()%4!=0)
        temp+='0';

    for(int i=temp.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        this.bn+=temp.charAt(i);
    }
    return this;
}
```

and in the activity there's a button that converts, but when I test and press on the button the app breaks

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            d1.decimal=Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
            b.DtoB(d1);
            t1.setText(b.bn);
        }
    });
```

can any one help me please ???

**Here is the logcat:**

```
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280): java.lang.NullPointerException 
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280): at com.example.converter.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34) 
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408) 
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816) 
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
```

Comment: I dont understand this, why are you not using Integer.toBinaryString(number);?

Comment: @Arash 
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.example.converter.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

Comment: 10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 09:16:15.831: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

Comment: @ahmedmaamoun : did you initialized your button b1? maybe its null

Comment: @Arash no its initialized

Comment: what line is MainActivity.java:34 ? a NPE could be not initializing the editText `e1`, or check the line 34 what does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check variable all are initialize perfectly . because some time objectc are created but it is null so can't work and throw java.lang.NullPointerException .....

```
 b1 , d1 , b ,t1
```

Comment: that was right i hadn't call the constructors of the object :) thanks @Pdev :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this...!

public class BinaryToDecimal {

        public int getDecimalFromBinary(int binary){

            int decimal = 0;
            int power = 0;
            while(true){
                if(binary == 0){
                    break;
                } else {
                    int tmp = binary%10;
                    decimal += tmp*Math.pow(2, power);
                    binary = binary/10;
                    power++;
                }
            }
            return decimal;
        }

        public static void main(String a[]){
            BinaryToDecimal bd = new BinaryToDecimal();
            System.out.println("11 ===> "+bd.getDecimalFromBinary(11));
            System.out.println("110 ===> "+bd.getDecimalFromBinary(110));
            System.out.println("100110 ===> "+bd.getDecimalFromBinary(100110));
        }
    }
```